# Am I not asking questions properly?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

In my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245093/setting-up-eclipse-ide-for-c-for-mac-osx), I asked for help to get Eclipse set up for C++ on Mac OSX. I understand it's a long post, but I've asked briefer variations of it only to end up deleting them because I came to the conclusion that they didn't provide enough detail. Am I providing too much detail? What should I do to improve my post?

Comment: *Personally* your post looks okay to me.  I'd say...just be patient.

Comment: The link directs me to your profile page, not your question.

Comment: I think that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245093/setting-up-eclipse-ide-for-c-for-mac-osx) is the question you meant to include in your link

Comment: That was asked only 7 hours ago. Wait another week or so.

Comment: Don't keep deleting and re-asking a post if it isn't worded properly.  Edit it to add/remove information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some SE sites where a question will get a good answer very quickly.  SO isn't one of them.

If you post a detailed question and look for a detailed answer, don't panic, it will (usually) come.  It takes time to create a good answer.

You often see people adding things like "*I need this NOW*" to the question title.  That is the worst thing you can do.

Comment: One can get a good answer quickly. It depends on how quickly one can fully understand the question, and especially how involved the answer is. Proper tagging (the relevant tags, and no irrelevant ones) and having an interesting question is an advantage there though.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the question you have up atm. For some people it might be too long to read. For most questions that dont get answers/views are because of the tags of the questions aren't popular. The [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/install) is not popular at all. Of course you have [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) in there as well but because of the other tags(which are probably correct) people might be like:`"Oh a C# question nice. Oh wait there's a tag in there which I have no clue about."` I'm not saying you should throw in some popular tags that have nothing to do with the question but I think the unpopular tags might be what's causing the lack of views/answers.

Comment: Also, the "big" language tags get *so many* questions a day that unless yours is great, many people will go for something quicker to understand/read.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yeah good point. Al though a question tagged with php is (almost) always answered within 10 minutes if it doesn't have any extra tags.